# Printing current date and time on each page

Tags: printing, cups

I'm often printing several versions of a document (e.g. a paper in progress). To keep track of the printouts I would like to print the date and time of printing onto *each page*, regardless of which application I'm using (although it would be okay if it works for PDF files only, if it happens automatically). I have seen Windows printer drivers including this feature, but haven't found any settings here (e.g., Canon iR3225) nor any hidden-CUPS-feature-I-could-activate-in-the-config-file.

Any ideas? Some sort of preprocessing I could inject into cups?

(I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a usable solution using convert from ImageMagick, the PDF services mentioned by nathang and Automator.

1. Start Automator, create a new "Print Plugin"
2. Drag the "run shell script" action to the right and enter the following script:

   ```
   export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   convert -size 400x50 xc:white -font Arial -pointsize 24 -gravity center -draw "fill grey50 text 0,0 '`/bin/date`'" /tmp/stamp.png
   cat
   ```
3. Add the "Watermark PDF Documents" action and add the file "/tmp/stamp.png" using the 'add...' button. (You probably have to create this file first, e.g. using `touch /tmp/stamp.png` in a Terminal). Then adjust the offset, scale and opacity as you like. I'm using x=480 y=820 scale=0.25 opacity=0.7.
4. Add the "Open Images in Preview" action.
5. Save the Automator script.

Now you should find a new action in the "PDF" drop-down menu of your printing dialog, which stamps the current date and time on each page and shows the result in Preview, from where you can print the document.

Comment: Your link is a 404. If you still have the script, can you re-upload it?

Comment: @grgarside Sorry I don't have the file any longer as I reinstalled my mac several times since then. But you can create it yourself using the description above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a PDF modification tool like [`Pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to add a watermark that contains the desired metadata.

Comment: I know about `pdftk`, and probably it's possible using it to write some script adding my timestamp to each page. But this does not solve the integration problem into the printing system -- the solution is sort of unusable if I have to go to the console pre-processing every PDF file I want to print.

Comment: How about integrating this with AppleScript?

Comment: Integrating into the system is the easy part, thanks to [PDF services](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004122222145585)